# Timeout when running stage on Bluemix DevOps pipeline

Tags: ibm-cloud, pipeline, devops

I'm running e2e tests in a stage in my Bluemix DevOps pipeline but it is exceeding the 60 minutes limit:

```
 The execution exceeded the time limit of 60 minutes.

 One possible solution is to split up your execution.
 Finished: ERRORED
```

Is there a way of increasing the stage timeout? I do not want to split my tests across different stages.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to change the timeout for a running build.  Instead of using different stages, you could try using multiple test jobs on your one stage as each job has the timeout of 60 minutes.  One possible way to break it down could be one job per test suite.